# Hangman checking logic

Tags: java

Hi I am new to programming and we have an assignment to create a hangman game. Now the problem I am having is the guessing. The program is guessing everything right and it's working correctly. though it doesn't print out the letters in the `JTextField`, or it rather does print out 1 letter but when i guess correct again the previous letter gets overwritten.

So any friendly soul out there who could lend a helping hand?

Heres my code for the checking:

```
  private class check implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try {  
            // Grabs the letter from the guessField and converts it into a char which can be used to compare against the word.
         guess = guessField.getText();

        guessField.setText("");
        char guess2 = guess.charAt(0);


        String displaySecret = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
            displaySecret += "*";


        //read in a guess
        int position = random.indexOf(guess2);
        //now position contains the index of guess inside secret, or
        //-1 if the guess was wrong

        String newDisplaySecret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
            if (i == position)
                newDisplaySecret += random.charAt(i); //newly guessed character
            else
                newDisplaySecret += displaySecret.charAt(i); //old state

        displaySecret = new String(newDisplaySecret);

        wordField.setText(displaySecret);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the way you initialize display secret from

```
String displaySecret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
        displaySecret += "*";
```

to

```
String displaySecret = wordField.getText();
if(displaySecret=NULL){/*case for fist execution*/
    displaySecret="";
    for (int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
    displaySecret += "*";
}
```

This will enable you to memorize the last entry from one guess to another. You can delete the entire if statement if your Label is correctly initialized.

There is however another problem with your code which is if you have several occurrences of the same letter in your random variable you will only find the first one.

The condition:

```
if(i=position)
```

should be

```
if (guess2 == random.charAt(i))
```

Comment: Im using a JTextField, and wordField.getText(displaySecret); is not applicable for string it says for me.

Comment: sorry it doesn't take an argument see edit. The getText() is applicable as it is inherited from JTextComponent.

Comment: Thanks it is working, except for now that it doesn't select all the A:s if a Word is banana for example

Comment: Thank you it's working you really helped me out a lot! Though i have one last problem if you would like to help me out?

Comment: Yeah sure what is the issue?

Comment: If you could help me solve this problem it would be great! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437734/why-is-this-code-not-working-hangman/19437886?noredirect=1#comment28913838_19437886

Answer (score 0):

```
wordField.setText(displaySecret);
```

to

```
wordField.setText(wordField.getText()+displaySecret);
```

Think that the code inside the world field replaces the value with the new one, the method declaration says it `set`, it is not `addText`.

Comment: It's not working since it still overwriting the previous letter.

Comment: then you have to store in memory or database all the past letters the user already inputted.

Comment: well it is storing it?