# Why is this code not working? Hangman

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a hangman game. Everything works fine, I have code ready to be used for failing the game and giving -1 to the guesses. Though when adding it to the else statement it gets duplicate equal to the length of the word and it also gives a guess—even though its right? I don't see what's wrong in the code? I believe it's my code when guessing wrong which is not placed right though I see no other way?

This is the code:

```
private class check implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      try {
         // Grabs the letter from the guessField and converts it into a char
         // which can be used to compare against the word.
         guess = guessField.getText();
         guessField.setText("");
         char guess2 = guess.charAt(0);

         // --------------------
         // Here is the guessing logic but it's currently
         // not working and you can not win since i haven't written code for
         // it yet. it's not selecting all the letters. for Example if
         // choosing A in a word such as Banana it only selects the first
         // a--------------------------- //
         String displaySecret = wordField.getText();
         if (displaySecret.equals("")) {/* case for fist execution */
            displaySecret = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < random.length(); i++)
               displaySecret += "_ ";
         }
         String newDisplaySecret = "";
         for (int v = 0; v < random.length(); v++) {
            if (guess2 == random.charAt(v)) {
               newDisplaySecret += random.charAt(v); // newly guessed
                                                     // character
            } else {
               newDisplaySecret += displaySecret.charAt(v); // old state
               guesses--;
               statusLabel.setText("Guesses left: " + guesses);
               missField.setText(missField.getText() + guess);
               if (guesses <= 0) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Game over! The word was: " + random);
                  guessField.setEditable(false);
                  wordField.setText("");
                  missField.setText("");
                  guesses = 7;
                  statusLabel.setText("Guesses left: " + guesses);
               }
            }
         }
         displaySecret = new String(newDisplaySecret);
         wordField.setText(displaySecret);
         if (displaySecret.equals(random)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Won! The Word was: "
                 + random);
            guesses = 7;
            statusLabel.setText("Guesses left: " + guesses);
            wordField.setText("");
            missField.setText("");
            guessField.setEditable(false);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `.equals(..)` for string comparison rather than `==`.

Comment: guess2 is a char .equal cant be applied to it

Comment: @Mccamer, that's char comparison, as you are comparing two chars.  By string comparison, I mean the line `if(displaySecret == ""){` where you are comparing two strings. Be sure to know the difference between a string and a char.

Comment: ok thanks for the tips i change it right now.

Comment: Though the problem is my guessing code further down i cant implement it correctly and i don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to check your word and generate "newDisplaySecret":

```
for (int v = 0; v < random.length(); v++) {
      if (guess2 == random.charAt(v)) {
           newDisplaySecret += random.charAt(v); // newly guessed
                                                 // character
        } else {
           newDisplaySecret += displaySecret.charAt(v);
}
```

Here is how you can determine whether the player guessed right or wrong:

```
if(newDisplaySecret.equals(displaySecret)){
    guesses --;

}
```

This needs to be placed after your check word code. Your code seems to decrement guesses for each letter in the word random.

Update display:

```
     displaySecret = new String(newDisplaySecret);
     wordField.setText(displaySecret);
```

Now that you know what the current state of affairs is for this move you can decide if the person has won or lost or just needs to continue playing:

```
if(guesses <= 0){
    /*place here instructions for loosing scenario*/
}else{
     if(displaySecret.equals(random)) {
         /*place here instructions for winning scenario*/
     }
    /*simply do nothing the game is neither lost or won*/
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: do you Think you can help me with a problem?

Answer (score 3):

If `random`is your Word, you iterate over each Character of it and then check whether each single character matches the guess you get for each character that doesn't match the guess a -1.

For Example: The Word is `Bananarama`and you guess a `n`your first and second matches will go to the else clause. then one time the if clause goes again, then the else and so on.

You have to

1. iterate over all characters, check whether they match or not
2. if a match occurs, replace the char and increase the counter
3. check if the counter of correct characters equals 0
4. if so, decrease the guesses

Some other tips: you should use `.toLower()` on your input and word string before comparsion to allow insensitivity for case

Some sample code:

```
int charsGuessedCorrectly;
for ( int i = 0; i < random.length( ); i++ )
{
    if ( random.charAt( i ) == guess )
    {
        charsGuessedCorrectly++;
        newDisplaySecret += random.charAt(v); // newly guessed
                                              // character
    }
}

if ( charsGuessedCorrectly == 0 )
{
    newDisplaySecret += displaySecret.charAt(v); // old state
    guesses--;
    statusLabel.setText("Guesses left: " + guesses);
    missField.setText(missField.getText() + guess);
    if (guesses <= 0) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
           "Game over! The word was: " + random);
       guessField.setEditable(false);
       wordField.setText("");
       missField.setText("");
       guesses = 7;
       statusLabel.setText("Guesses left: " + guesses);
}
```

Comment: it is already checking if it's matching. it works when i run the program. i have an if statement saying if(guess2 == random.charAt(v)) where it checks if the char is correct and then in the else statement that's where it all goes wrong since the guesscharr gets duplicated by the length of the Word and the guesses give -- even if the char is correct

Comment: all the Words are uppercase and read from a txt file and im using a documentfilter only allowing uppercase letters in the guessfield

Comment: i tried this if(!(guess2 == random.charAt(v)) guess-- but then i got stringIndexOutOfbound exception.

Comment: I think you get me wrong or i missunderstood your question. I attached some sample code to my answer to clear this up.

Comment: i couldn't get that code to work do you Think you can edit the code above and insert it? so i can try it out?

Comment: I now added your code in the corresponding statements. You just have to replace your whole for statement with my code

Comment: well basically nothing happens, and i think it's because charsguessedcorrectly has to be instantiated with = 0. But i have made it in another way now that half works but still gives me problems. It only checks the first letter correctly or else gives me wrong guess.

Comment: int Values are initialized with 0 automatically in Java. But its a good point for Code readability